# How does Castle.ActiveRecord override virtual properties?

Tags: c#, activerecord, attributes, castle-activerecord

In active record to write a model you write:

```
[ActiveRecord("TableName")]
public class Model
{
   [Property("SomeField")]
   public virtual string SomeField { get; set; };

   [Property("SomeLazyField"), Lazy= true]
   public virtual string SomeLazyField { get; set; };

}
```

If the field is lazy it must fetch it on the first access, so how does the Property attribute override the property and fetches the SomeLazyField value?

Comment: cross-posted (with answer) here: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/bef5f4c8c390b3ea

Comment: Yeh that's me in that mailing list :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from Rohan:

> I would imagine that AR generates a
>   dynamic proxy and uses interceptors to
>   perform lazy loading. I am not
>   familiar with AR, but have been using
>   Dynamic Proxy and Windsor container
>   for the last year, there are plenty of
>   examples that demonstrate these
>   concepts.

Quoted from Roelof Blom:

> Actually it's NH that generates the
>   proxy.